# Print a log message in hardhat test suite just when --verbose is specified

Tags: hardhat

Hardhat has [--verbose](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/troubleshooting/verbose-logging) logging for its own logs. Is it possible to control user logs and print them just if verbose logging is selected as well? I want to have a clean result when I run my tests, but I do have many logs in my tests, so I just want to print them whenever I specify verbose logging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just override the `test` task of hardhat:

```
task("test")
  .addFlag("debug", "Print debugging logs")
  .setAction(async (taskArgs, hre, runSuper) => {
    hre.debugMode = taskArgs.debug ?? false;
    hre.logDebug = hre.debugMode ? console.log.bind(console) : function () {};
    return runSuper();
  });
```